# Bitbucket merge won't update master branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to get familiar with **GIT** and **Bitbucket**.
I've firstly created a `master` branch and then pushed all to it(`add origin..`), since I already had some stuff done in my project.

Then my commands looked like this:

```
git branch dev
git checkout dev
```

Do some work..

```
git add . -A
git commit -m "Some work done"
git push -u origin dev
```

Back to master..

```
git checkout master
git merge dev
```

The problem is, that since folders on my computer are now in sync both on master and dev branches, the master branch on Bitbucket is still not updating and it's the source i've uploaded initially.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to push the changes for `master` branch as well.

  ```
  git push origin master
  ```

  If that fails complaining about upstream branch not set, try:

  ```
  git push -u origin master
  ```
- If you just want to push all the refs in your `refs/heads` (i.e. all the local branches), you can run this command:

  ```
  git push origin --all
  ```
- Also note that any tags are not pushed to the remote automatically either. You need to specify the tag name explicitly:

  ```
  git push origin my-new-tag
  ```
- You could also ask git to push all the tags (under `refs/tags`) in your local repo:

  ```
  git push origin --tags
  ```
- You could also chain these commands like this for example to push all branches and all tags:

  ```
  git push origin --all --tags
  ```

**More info about branches in git**:

You can think of branches in git as just lightweight pointers to keep track of the commits. When such a branch pointer is moved or updated in your local repo, and you invoke a `push`, git is going to update the branch pointer on the remote side, as well as send all the commits between the current and the new branch pointer to the remote.

When you merge one branch into another (like you merged `dev` into `master`), you would be either doing a fast-forward merge (both the branch pointers will point essentially to the same commit) or create a new merge commit which the branch `master` is going to point to.

Again, these changes are visible only locally until you push them to the remote.

Comment: @intelis - Updated the answer with some more info which should give you a better idea of branches and merges.